# Problems with definition of a function with matrices

Tags: functions, function-construction

I want to define the product between two matrices. If I don't define it as function everything is fine (lines at the end of the image), but when I try to define it as a function it gets strange things. What is going on? And how do I solve it?
[image]
The first one is

```
Okubo[x03_,y03_] = \[Omega]*(x03.y03) - \[Omega]*\[Omega] (y03.x03) - (\[Omega] - \[Omega]*\[Omega])/3 Tr[x03.y03] IdentityMatrix [3];

Okubo[e, e] // MatrixForm
```

while the second one (working properly) is

```
\[Omega]*(e.e) - \[Omega]*\[Omega] (e.e) - (\[Omega] - \[Omega]*\[Omega])/3 Tr[e.e] IdentityMatrix [3]
```

The lement "e" is the the one on which I'm testing the thing and is

```
e = ( { {2, 0, 0},{0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}} );
```

Comment: it will easier to find out why if you post the Mathematica code.  From screen shot it should not do that. But without the code hard to try.

Comment: Thank you, I added the code... do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:=`

```
Clear["Global`*"]
e = ({{2, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}});
Okubo[x03_,y03_] := ω*(x03 . y03) - ω*ω (y03.x03) - (ω - ω*ω)/3 
     Tr[x03.y03] IdentityMatrix[3];

Okubo[e, e] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(ω*(e . e) - ω*ω (e.e) - (ω - ω*ω)/3 Tr[e . e] IdentityMatrix[3]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The reason is, when you used immediate assignment, then Mathematica evaluated the body of the function immediately. This resulted in

```
Okubo[x03_,y03_] = ω*(x03 . y03) - ω*ω (y03 . x03) - (ω - ω*ω)/3 
    Tr[x03 . y03] IdentityMatrix[3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is not what you want. Because it did not know that `x03` and `y03` were matrices. But with delayed assignments, it did the right `.` operation since the arguments are now known to be matrices.

It is always best to define functions using delayed assignment unless there is specific reason not to.

Comment: didn't seem to work... I copy and pasted... am I missing something? https://gyazo.com/c3e38f5f3de56aae56b4a949fb8eff99

Comment: @Dac0 did you use `:=` or `=`

Comment: Now I saw :) Please edit the code in the corrected version with := future leggibility :) Thank you